# A Perl script that internally calls a Linux command and saves the output to a file?

Tags: linux, perl

I'm trying to write a Perl script that internally calls "ls " and saves the output to a file. Displays the file on the screen in pages, allowing the user to hit a key to go to the next page?

Any ideas?
Thanks

So Far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$command = system("ls /bin/usr/account\ users/");
```

Comment: Not well structured question. -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to rewrite `ls | more`. Do you really need to do this?

The program below opens the file `temp.txt` for writing. It then uses`qx` (the equivalent of backticks) to get the output from a command and write it to the file.

The same file is then reopened for reading, and twenty lines at a time are sent to `STDOUT`.

To allow character IO from the keyboard the read mode is set to 3 and `ReadKey` is called to fetch the next keypress. These calls require the `Term::ReadKey` module to be specified in a `use` statement at the top of the program. It is a core module and so shouldn't need installing

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ReadKey;

open my $fh, '>', 'temp.txt' or die $!;
print $fh qx(ls /bin/usr/account/users/);

open $fh, '<', 'temp.txt' or die $!;

ReadMode(3);

my $n = 20;
while (<$fh>) {

  print;

  if (--$n == 0) {
    print "-- More  --";
    ReadKey(0);
    $n += 20;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember `less` is `more` nowadays

Answer (score 3):

To save the command's output to `$command` wants

```
my $command = `ps aux`;
```

or, maybe better,

```
my @command = `ps aux`;
```

the latter of which will store each line of the command's output as a separate element of the list.  After that, you can do with `$command` or `@command` as you wish -- displaying its contents, writing its contents to a file, both displaying and writing, whatever you like.

To write to a file,

```
my $filename = "MY_FILENAME";
# ...
open FILE, '>>', $filename;
print FILE @command;
close FILE;
```

You can use `'>'` instead of `'>>'` if you prefer to overwrite the file rather than to append to it.  You can use any word in place of `FILE`, though to all-capitalize such a word is conventional in any case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still having problems trying to output the result from the command ps aux to a file. I've tried $command=system("ps aux"), '>:crlf', $file;  open FILE, '>>', $file; close FILE;

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using `system` with a command like:

```
ps aux >/tmp/myfile
```

or, if you want to process it in Perl, something like:

```
open (INSTREAM, "ps aux |");
```

and you can then read it lile any other "file":

```
while (<INSTREAM>) { ... }
```